# ObservableCollection visualizer - does such a thing exist?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, observablecollection, debuggervisualizer

I am finding myself working with ObservableCollection quite a bit.  I've looked around, but I can't seem to find an ObservableCollection Debug Visualizer.

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: Why would a visualizer for `ObservableCollection<T>` be any different than visualizer for any `IList<T>`? Or would that be enough?

Comment: @svick When debugging the visualizer appears for List<T>, but not for ObservableCollection<T>.

Comment: [I don't see any difference between the two](http://i.imgur.com/ChfAm.png). Maybe you have some special visualizer for `List<T>`?

Comment: @svick.  Wow, you are partially correct.  I can see the visualizer fine in a Console app project.  But I am in a Windows Phone 7 project and all it shows me is [this](http://imgur.com/g6e2S).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Here's a commercial tool for $50...  [Mole 2010](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/using-mole-2010-to-analyze-collections/)
2. You could override the `.ToString()` for the class that you are wrapping with `ObservableCollection`.
3. Otherwise, you can tweak what the visualizer shows you with the DebuggerDisplayAttribute.

   ```
   [DebuggerDisplay("Employee ( {FullName} )")]
   public class Employee
   {
       ...
   }
   ```
4. And if that's not enough, you can write your own visualizer. There are tons of articles out there for that.

   a. [MSDN Magazine: DataTips, Visualizers and Viewers Make Debugging .NET Code a Breeze](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163974.aspx)

   b. [MSDN Library: How to: Write a Visualizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2zc529c.aspx)

   c. [MSDN Forums: How do I implement a custom debug visualizer?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/vsdebug/thread/957379c9-ee62-49e1-892b-add7f2e61951)

   d. [Code Project: A Generic List and Dictionary Debugger Visualizer for VS.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/ListVisualizer.aspx)

   e. [Code Project: Create a Debugger Visualizer in 10 Lines of Code](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/trace/ImageVisualizer.aspx)